# Error message of log4net is truncated in log file

Tags: c#, console, .net-4.0, log4net

I have these code:

```
class Program
{
    protected static ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            logger.Error("error", exception);
        }
    }
}
```

when I run it from my computer, visual studio, the error in log file is

> 2019-09-12 14:07:19,302 [10] ERROR InspectionEmail.Program [(null)] - error
>   System.Exception: 1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>      at InspectionEmail.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\TFS\XXXXXX\Manufacturing\Main\PartsTracking\InspectionEmail\InspectionEmail\Program.cs:line 30

when I run it from server, the error in log file is

> 2019-09-12 14:06:55,744 [1] ERROR InspectionEmail.Program [

why is that? what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try checking if the web config part matches locally and on the server, specifically check the MaxSizeRollBackups,

```
  <MaxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
```

Also check the maximumFileSize is not set to something very small on the server